# Make a graphical component reusable in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have create a graphical component for my aplicatión for iphone to reuse it in several windows. For example: a box with description from an object.

Which is the best way to make it? Is it with a `UIVIewController`?.

```
    @interface DescriptionBox : UIViewController 
{
    ...
    }
```

And then I use it in a window:

```
@implementation WindowOne

- (void)loadView {

    ...

    DescriptionBox *component = [[DescriptionBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)];
    [[self view] addSubview:[component view]];

}
```

and other:

```
@implementation WindowTwo

- (void)loadView {

    ...

    DescriptionBox *component = [[DescriptionBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)];
    [[self view] addSubview:[component view]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use UIViewControllers. Take a look at how [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) is organized. It's a class that enables you to show some popup messages with activity indicators, it adjusts to UIViewController rotations and knows when there's a keyboard visible to re-layout itself.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases your component should subclass UIView. From that point you can wrap your custom functionality inside this class, and then you add it to your view programmatically, just like any other subview.